# I can't draw path with using gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

I with using gmaps.js examples and documents try to draw path on google maps but it don't draw anything.

my code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Show Vehicles</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function(){

      map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 53.361320,
        lng: -6.505633,
        click: function(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
      });
      path = [[53.361320,-6.505633],[53.361330,-6.505643],[53.361335,-6.505650],[53.361343,-6.505652],[53.361352,-6.505668],[53.361347,-6.505672],[53.361342,-6.505688],[53.361347,-6.505700],[53.361337,-6.505717],[53.361352,-6.505722],[53.361342,-6.505735],[53.361357,-6.505740],[53.361372,-6.505753],[53.361383,-6.505758]];

      map.drawPolyline({
        path: path,
        strokeColor: '#131540',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 6
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me

Comment: Im not an expert, but shouldn't you pass some kind ob instances of sth. like `point` or anything to `map.drawPolyline`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I set no css for result with this I can see genereted map

```
h1{
font-size:2em;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin:5px;
}
#map{
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #ccc;
}
#map.large{
  height:500px;
}

.overlay{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:60px;
  line-height:80px;
  opacity:0.8;
  background:#4477aa;
  border:solid 3px #336699;
  border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #333;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #666;
  padding:0 4px;
}

.overlay_arrow{
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-16px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
}
.overlay_arrow.above{
  bottom:-15px;
  border-left:16px solid transparent;
  border-right:16px solid transparent;
  border-top:16px solid #336699;
}
.overlay_arrow.below{
  top:-15px;
  border-left:16px solid transparent;
  border-right:16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:16px solid #336699;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually looks correct (and a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f24K9/1/) seems to show it working at least on my browser).  I think you need to set a `zoom` to see the `Polyline` (it is a rather small line) possibly like this([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f24K9/2/))):

```
map = new GMaps({
  div: '#map',
  zoom: 19,
  lat: 53.361320,
  lng: -6.505633,
  click: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `path` consists of arrays of numbers. It should be an array of `google.maps.LatLng` which can then be passed to `maps.drawPolyline` instead.
See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple